# array allocates not wanted memory

Tags: c

Problem statement:
 Given a sequence of integers. For each group of 5 succesive elements
(1..5, 6..10 etc) find the minimum and put it in another array (the
length 1/5 from the initial array).
Use a function that gets a pointer to a sequence of 5 elements and a
pointer to an integer where it will store the result.

```
void main()
{
int n1,i,z,k;
int v[50],x[10];

printf("length of array:");
scanf("%d" , &n1);

k = -1;

readArray ( n1, v );
for (i=0; i<=n1; i++)
{    
    searchArray ( &k, &v[i], &x[k] );
}
writeArray ( k , x );
}
```

v[i] is the initial array, x[k] the resulted array and k points where in x the result should be put.

```
void searchArray ( int *k, int * v, int * x)
{

int i,z;
bool dif;

dif = false;
z = z+1;
if (v[i-1] == (v[i]-1))
{
    dif = true;
    if ((dif == true) && (z == 4))
    {
        *k = *k+1;
        x[*k] = v[i-4];
        z = 0;
        if (v[i]+1 == v[i+1])
        {
            i = i+1;
        }
    } 
}
else if ( dif != true )
     {
         z = 0;
     }
}
```

the problem: for an array from 1 to 10 the result is x[0] = 134513473 x[1] = 6 and if i look at x[-1] is 1. so instead of putting 1 in x[0] it puts it in x[-1] and x[0] return the memory adress.

Comment: AH, [tag:homework]! **plz-send-me-teh-codez**

Comment: Come back with a new question when you have a specific problem to report. plz-send-me-teh-codez type of questions don't fit our site.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the line:

```
z = z+1;
```

You haven't initialized `z` to anything, so everything that uses `z` after that is using garbage.  Your next line is:

```
if (v[i-1] == (v[i]-1))
```

Since `i` is uninitialized, you are processing garbage again.  Not a happy state of affairs.

Your function doesn't need `k` as an argument if you design it right.  You will need to modify the call, though, to pass the correct offset in the array.  (At the moment, you are scanning 0..4, 1..5, 2..6, instead of 0..4, 5..9, 10..14.)